# I'm having trouble viewing other users in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the users controller for my app I have a method for viewing the posts generated by users, but when you go to the index page and click on another user, the page of the currently logged in user shows up but the url is for the user I just clicked onto.

This is the method in my users controller

```
def feed
  @title = "Feed"
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) # This is the problem
  feed = Feed.new(@user)

render 'show_feed'
end
```

I'm also having trouble understanding the difference between session[:user_id] and params[:id]. If I change session[:user_id] to params[:id] while on the page, of the user I just clicked onto, their posts are then shown, but when I go back to the logged in user's page I get the error "Couldn't find User with 'id'=user_id" in "app/controllers/users_controller.rb:59:in `feed'" So my question is, what do I need to pass into @user = User.find() to get the correctly generated page/s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you're clickiing on a link to see some OTHER user, the link has an "id" embedded in it which is passed in the params, so you would do...

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Your link to go back to the logged in user is incorrect, but you haven't shown that link.  It should most probably be something like

```
<%= link_to user_path(session[:user_id]) %>
```

From the description of your problem you may be doing...

```
<%= link_to user_path('user_id') %>
```

... which doesn't make sense... it means literally go to the user record with the id of "user_id"

Comment: I think that's a new question. You should post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

`session` is data (usually stored in a cookie) that is persistent from one request to another and that expires at the end of the browser session. A common use is to store the id of the logged in user.

By passing that to `User.find` you're entirely ignoring the user id that is in the URL. You should be using `params[:id]` (unless your routes are naming that segment of your url differently)

Your problem when you "go back" is not clear to me (I can't even tell if we're talking about the same controller action) but at a guess either that page doesn't have an id in the URL, or the routing is calling it something else, or (and this is a little messy) you intend to fall back to the current user when there is no id in the URL in which case you need to be using either `params[:id]` or `session[:user_id]` depending on what's there.

Comment: OK. So then, how do I get rails to differentiate between the two. This is the url of the logged in user http://localhost:3000/users/user_id/feed and this would be the url of any other user http://localhost:3000/users/#/feed

Comment: There's a literal "user_id" in the URL? Should these be going to the same action?